# PHP SNMP get Object_ID (OID)

Tags: php, snmp

I have a php script that is attempting to get a specific piece of data. I am using the `snmprealwalk` function but the page is not returning anything.

```
<?php
$a = snmprealwalk("192.168.107.130", "public", ".2.6.1.2.1.33.6.5.1.2.2.1"); 
for (reset($a); $i = key($a); next($a)) {
    echo "$i: $a[$i]<br />\n";
}
?>
```

I know there is data there because if I simply take out the long `iso_ID` I will get all the data. This data contains the `key` or `iso_ID` I need to call a specific value.

How do I call a specific `object_id` using the `php` and `snmp` functions? What am I doing wrong? I am using **php 5.3.28**.

Comment: `error_reporting(-1);` and/or `var_dump($a);`

Comment: Interesting loop you got there, where did you see that looping is done like that? On top of basic debugging, like checking what `$a` is, what exactly can we help you out with seeing we can't run reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: Is that the actual OID you're querying?

Comment: No, the actual OID is this .3.6.1.2.1.43.16.5.1.2.1.1

Comment: @N.B. I got the loop from this example http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmpwalkoid.php. I guess im looking for any examples or references that queries a specific OID. the example i am using does not seem to work . Is it the php version perhaps?

Comment: Try 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.16.5.1.2.1.1 instead. You might want to check if an OID is walkable by running CLI command `snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 192.168.107.130 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.16.5.1.2.1.1`